# After POST, weird redirect to iana.org follows

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-voting

I'm using django-voting: https://github.com/brosner/django-voting/tree/master/voting
And after my post, I'm redirected here: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/#c40

```
<form method="POST" action="/comments/{{ comment.id }}/up/vote/">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <button type="submit">Thumbs Up!</button>
</form>
```

The vote is created and I can see it in the admin.

No where in my application do I have this kind of redirect. Nor can I find this line of code in django-voting where it would have this redirect. Has this happened to anyone else, if so how'd you solve this?

I just want to be redirected the same page after the casted the vote. So I tried `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ event.get_absolute_url }}" />` thinking that it might override. But this doesn't seem to work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that somewhere in your logic you redirect to `"example.com"`.  example.com is owned by the IANA and redirects to http://www.iana.org/domains/example/.

Also, the "#c40" at the end of the url makes me think that Django is trying to redirect back to some page with a `c40` anchor, possibly in order to have the thing you just voted on in view.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the Sites framework? (Do you have a Sites model in your admin?) If yes, this may be due to having an instance of a Site model with the domain name "example.org" which is the default.

Furthermore, there may be a fixture that reloads 'example.org' into the Sites each time you do something with the database, such as a migration with South, for example.

Answer (score 1):

That redirect happens when you hit one of the example domains, listed in [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606).

There's something somewhere in your code that's pushing to example.com or another one of the example domains.